# Docker Image and it's Kubernetes Pod differ

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry, kubernetes-pod, docker-image, docker-layer

I modified the contents in my Docker-Image and ran it's Kubernetes Pod. However, the Kubernetes Pod had the contents of the old version of the Docker Image and not the Modified One.

How is it possible?

I am guessing that the K8s worker node is trying to fetch as many layers from the local as possible and only few from the docker-registry.
How to solve this issue such that every time the K8s worker node pull all the layers of the docker image from the Registry only?

Answer (score 3):

Set `imagePullPolicy` to `Always`.

Sample:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  containers:
    - name: image-name
      image: my-image:0.0.1
      imagePullPolicy: Always # <<--here
```

> The default pull policy is `IfNotPresent` which causes the kubelet to skip pulling an image if it already exists. If you would like to always force a pull, set it to `Always`.

[Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images)

Answer (score 1):

Use `imagePullPolicy: Always` in your deployment

This option comes in handy if you deploy your application too often (Typical use case is CI/CD).

and one more thing if you want your image should be build fresh without any cache from local use `--no-cache` command in docker build command.

```
docker build -t myimage/imagename . --no-cache
```